# Run-time error '1004' This file is already open in Protected View

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a Macro which reads data from another Excel file. If the file is already opened by the user Excel tries to reopen the file - this is fine so far.

However if the file is opened in Protected View then the macro stops at this line:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("C6").value
```

With the Error:

```
Run-time error '1004' This file is already open in Protected View
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: since you are just reading data from the file, can you set the Read Only argument to True `Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("C6").value, ReadOnly:=True`

Answer (score 0):

For reading I recommend Scott Holtzman's solution:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="FileName", ReadOnly:=True
```

For other cases you can remove the protected mode by:

```
Do While Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0
    Application.ProtectedViewWindows(1).Edit
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.OnTime` works fine if there is no open workbook, but not if the apparently active workbook is in protected view (since a protected view window can't be the active window).

One solution is to programmatically enable editing in any protected view windows, but that's bad security practice.

Instead of this, I do a little test, and if it seems that a protected view window is in front, I create a new window temporarily, run the `Application.OnTime`, then close the temporary workbook.

```
' Fix: OnTime fails if "active" window is protected view
If Application.Windows.Count > 0 And ActiveWindow Is Nothing Then
    Dim bTempWkbk As Boolean
    bTempWkbk = True
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
End If
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"), "OnTimeFunction"
If bTempWkbk Then
    wb.Close False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This worked for me:

```
Sub ActivateProtectedWorkbook(fileName As String)

Dim wbProtected As Workbook
If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count
        If Application.ProtectedViewWindows(i).Workbook.Name = fileName Then
            Set wbProtected = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(i).Workbook
        End If
    Next
End If
wbProtected.Activate
End Sub
```

fileName mustn't include the full path. This may not work if the file isn't opened already and you run into another error due to a corrupted file or something.

In case you need to remove the full path from the fileName, use this:

```
Function RemoveFilePath(fileName As String) As String
'This sub removes the full path from fileName leaving only the file's name.
'e.g. C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\Worksheet Consulting\John\7.28\Hobson - Copy.xlsx
'    --> Hobson - Copy.xlsx

myStr = fileName
Do
    myInt = InStr(1, myStr, "\")
    myStr = Right(myStr, Len(myStr) - myInt)
Loop Until InStr(1, myStr, "\") = 0

RemoveFilePath = myStr

End Function
```

You can call the code as such:

```
On Error GoTo Activate
Set tempWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName, , True)
GoTo WasClosed
Activate:
noPath = RemoveFilePath(fileName)
Call ActivateProtectedWorkbook(noPath)
WasClosed:
On Error GoTo 0
```